# Snowflake Create Materilaized view on self Join

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a materialized view on table which will have latest data.
The query looks liks this

```
Create Materialized view t1_latest as
select c1,c2,dt from t1
join
(select max(dt) maxdt from t1) t2
ON t1.dt = t2.maxdt
```

dt being the date field.

Now as we know Materialized view does not allow subquery or window function. Is there a way to rewrite the query to create the Materialized view with latest date. latest date cannot be considered as current_date or hardcoded.

Another approach is to create a view with join and then create the Materialized view on top of that. But the problem there is we will loose the advantage of Materialized view being calculated before hand.

Any suggestion.

Comment: Materialized views are pretty basic in Snowflake.  You'll have to use a regular view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In case if I use view does not It will process the whole query every time the view is called.

Answer (score 0):

You'd actually gain exactly the same amount of performance gain if your table was clustered by `dt` and you just put a standard view over it with the same logic you have above.  This will prune the table in the same manner as creating a materialized view would do.

If the table is already clustered on something else, then creating a simple materialized view with the `dt` as your cluster key will provide the same benefits, but also have the benefits of the ability to simply query the base table and have the query optimizer assist with choosing the best pruning option:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#how-the-query-optimizer-uses-materialized-views

Edited per comment:
Not sure I understand why you can't use a task/stream, but what if you did something a bit different with task & stream.

1. Create a stream...when the stream has data, you could execute a task that executes a stored procedure.
2. The Stored Procedure would evaluate the table to see if there were
   more than 1 distinct value for `dt`.  If there is, it would delete the older data from the table.

In Snowflake, the delete would essentially just be a metadata operation, since all of the micropartitions would contain the same date based on how you describe the data being loaded.

Comment: I agree, But our client requirement is to have a table which only contains lastest data. without using any etl tool. So basically t1 table is getting created using snowpipe and plan was to put materialized view on top of table. we cannot use task and stream as we dont know the exact time of file coming in s3

Comment: @danD I've edited with a second option based on the "table requirement" that you've clarified.  It's a bit outside the box.  In addition, you may want to explain to the customer that the performance of a view over a clustered table will be the same as a MV with just 1 date of data in it.  They likely don't understand how things work.